# Increase the limited file upload size on deployed environment (Heroku + Cloudflare)

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, heroku, cloudflare

I'm dealing with an issue which hinders us uploading files to our platform. The point is that when I upload a file with any size from local development environment, files are uploaded without problem. But if I upload the files from deployed platform only until a certain size works. E.g. 30MB file upload throws no error and files are uploaded successfully but 200MB file upload threw either `413 (Payload Too Large)` or `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` errors which can be seen on browser console.

I just wanted to know if there's a limitation on Heroku or Cloudflare ? Or is it environment issue ?

This was never the case before and everything was working fine.

I'm using Node.js, Heroku, Cloudflare(registrar) and in the front end without framework plain JS.

```
    const favicon = require('serve-favicon');

    const config = require('./config');

    let app = express();

    if (app.get("env") === "production") {
        const enforce = require('express-sslify');
        app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
    }

    app.use(express.json({ limit: '300mb' }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "300mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(cors({
        origin: ['https://www.originwebsite.ch/'],
        methods : ['POST','GET']
    }));
    
    app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','image','favicon.ico')));

    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
    });

    const server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); })
```

The file upload is made to AWS S3 by chunks. I'm also using helmet.js and a rateLimiterMiddleware but deactivating them didn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/413-request-entity-too-large-how-to-increase-the-size/330117/7